# Developer Documentation Builder

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation

I am trying to build a developer documentation for my web app in the style of this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

The features I am looking for is that it has a left vertical navigation bar, and the documentation text is on the right, along with code sections. Instead of me creating everything from HTML/CSS from scratch, I am wondering if there is a website builder that I can use to drag and drop the features I want such as the vertical navigation bar, and code blocks, etc, or other methods to build such documentation?